# Redirect directory with htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

This question has been asked and addressed numerous times, but I ran into an instance where the usual solution doesn't work;

Tried and true: `RedirectMatch 301 .*/author/.*$  /` worked on one server but not another.

To be specific, we need to redirect all requests for WordPress author archives to the front of the site. Elsewhere, people have asked why would anyone want to do that. That's outside the scope of the question but it's to hide author names. Systematic alternatives exist within the CMS, but they act differently for actual author names (redirects to homepage) and no-such-author (404 page not found). That's too many clues. Other methods exist to nickname authors, but they're all leaky.

So we used the code above on all sites on one Apache server and it worked like a champ. on On nginx server, we tried numerous versions of Redirect and Rewrite to no avail. Shared hosting provider wasn't much help.

need to block http://domain.com/blog/author/name

and http://domain.com/author/name

With something other than:

```
RedirectMatch 301 .*/author/.*$  /
```

Comment: This other server have `allowoverride fileinfo` set in the directory that your htaccess file (and the `RedirectMatch`) is in?

Comment: No clean way to check on this shared server - but other .htaccess rewrite rules work (e.g. `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`) suggesting yes `allowoverride fileinfo` or `all` is set.

Comment: If you have other rules, are you sure those aren't affecting the redirect (note that mod_alias (redirectmatch) is a different module than mod_rewrite (rewriterule) and thus both end up getting applied *to the same request*)

Comment: I reviewed, but same rules played well together on the other (apache) server. Not to say it's nginx issue - I'm guessing something in the nginx configration vs. host w/ apache where it works.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/author/ http://www.your-domain.com/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/author/ http://www.your-domain.com/
```

Comment: I have the same problem, can't redirect `/author/` pages using htaccess. I was able to redirect the `?author=...` pages sucessfully, but I think wordpress' own redirects are messing with me.